# Microsoft Access 2010 - How to create lookup criteria based on prior column in VBA or SQL

Tags: ms-access

I have table 1 with 4 columns. The 3rd Column was a lookup, and a value comes from table 2.  Table 1, field 4 requires that one of Tables 5-8 is chosen as the lookup choices, not just one specific table. How do I filter to the correct table by using VBA or SQL?

Eg  value in column 3 = BU.  If the answer is AT, the correct table is XXX; if the answer is BU, the correct table is YYY, for column 4 lookup.

Comment: What does the SQL for 3rd Column look like?

Comment: This sounds like a poor design. If the tables 5- 8 contain related information then they should probably be in one table with an type Identifier that would let you filter down or join the correct values?

Comment: It is a lookup to a sub-table. So Lets say we are doing assets. So the 2rd Column is a lookup to the "asset type table", which has 3 columns, the Asset Type 2 digit code, the description as the 2nd field, and the 3rd field is a table name that holds all of that type of asset. So the 3rd column I want to be a lookup to the asset table that corresponds with the Asset type. There are about 10 different tables it could be.

Comment: The assets cannot all be on one table as their attributes are totally different. For instance, land and vehicles. This is a data gathering exercise, and I must emulate the underlying system. Some of the tables relate not to assets but to processes in other modules. So it is not quite as simple as what you think it is.

Comment: I had thought a method to solve this might be to have a view that has all of the asset id's and types, which is a total of all of the available data rows, but the problem is that the data rows probably won't exist until 5 minutes before they are to be called on, so it would have to be auto update. I am not sure how to accomplish that solution either. But it is an option to look at.

Comment: @edg See sample table and data that I edited above.  Now, what would tblBU look like, and how would it differ from tblLA ??